# Adding doorways to polygonal rendering of building using QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, rendering

I am working on rendering some buildings and their internal floorplans for the company map, but I have run into an issue where I'm not quite sure how to mark doorways.

Has anyone already come up with a simple solution for this?

Ideally, I would want the CAD-looking doorway sweep showing open direction, but I could live with just a gap in the outline of the room to mark doorways. Using QGIS 3.22.14

This is the current building I'm working on:

[image]

Comment: Create one wedge buffer, copy it, rotate, move. Set the symbology same color as the floor plan